# Spring-boot-actuator exposing 0 endpoints

Tags: java, spring-boot-actuator

I am trying to expose the /actuator/health endpoint in my spring-boot application, but my log states that zero endpoints are exposed. I have seen some documentation that states that the health endpoint is the only endpoint that is enabled by default but it returns 404 for me.

**Log from startup of application:**

```
{"@timestamp":"2022-06-29T09:50:59.441+02:00","@version":1,"message":"Exposing 0 endpoint(s) beneath base path '/actuator'","logger_name":"org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.web.EndpointLinksResolver","thread_name":"main","level":"INFO","level_value":20000,"caller_class_name":"org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.web.EndpointLinksResolver","caller_method_name":"<init>","caller_file_name":"EndpointLinksResolver.java","caller_line_number":58}
```

Accessing /actuator also shows that no endpoints are exposed:

```
{"_links":{"self":{"href":"http://localhost:8000/actuator","templated":false}}}
```

I've looked at several other similar posts but none of the fixes provided works for me.
I do have my own endpoint as well in a **@RestController** that I thought might be interfering, but commenting it out its Post/Get-mappings did not help either.

---

**My pom.xml is as follows:**

```
<parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.6.6</version>
        <relativePath />
</parent>

...

<dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

---

**In my application.yaml I have tried the following:**

```
server:
  port: 8000

management:
  health:
    probes:
      enabled: true
    livenessstate:
      enabled: true
    readinessstate:
      enabled: true

  endpoint:
    health:
      probes:
        enabled: true
      show-details: always
      enabled: true

  endpoints:
    web:
      exposure:
        include: '*'
    enabled-by-default: true
```

Other settings in the **application.yaml** (like changing the port) works fine, so I know that the application.yaml is at least being used.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Since spring-boot 2x these endpoints are disabled and you need to enable them. You can try adding the following to your properties:

```
endpoints:
  enabled: false
  health:
    enabled: true
```

I also tried it via

```
management:
  endpoint:
    health:
      enabled: true
```

but that didn't work on the platform where I deployed it (WebLogic)

Comment: I tried both 
```
endpoints:
  enabled: false
  health:
    enabled: true
```

and

```
endpoints:
  enabled: true
  health:
    enabled: true
```


But I still get the same message of `exposing 0 endpoint(s)` and /actuator/health returns 404

Comment: I ment have you tried it when not defining them in management? So if you look at it from a .properties point of view it's `endpoints.health.enabled=true` vs `management.endpoint.health.enabled=true`

Comment: Yes sorry I was a little unclear, that is what I tried after reading your post. But the issue is still there. Maybe I can make a custom one instead as a workaround.