# Spring Boot : Missing Endpoints Exposed for Actuator

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-boot-actuator

I know that the question is not new (similar asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72798403/spring-boot-actuator-exposing-0-endpoints) )

I am trying to expose actuator endpoint for metrics

here are relevant definitions from application.properties :

```
management.endpoints.enabled-by-default=true
management.endpoints.web.exposure.include=health,metrics
management.endpoint.metrics.enabled=true
management.server.port=8090
```

Here imports from Pom.xml

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-dataformat-cbor</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>org.springframework.kafka</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-kafka</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
</dependency>
```

When starting app , I am getting

```
Exposing 1 endpoint(s) beneath base path '/actuator
```

while expected 2 ( health and metrics )
Is there missing something in definitions ? Thanks in advnance

Answer (score 1):

All actuator endpoints from `spring-boot-3.x` also(metrics, health), are under `/actuator` path.

For example metrics = `/actuator/metrics` and health = `/actuator/health`

Comment: Thanks @Andrei Lisa for quick reply , trying to access /actuator/metrics - getting 404 error . /actuator/health - succeeded, Using spring boot 2.3.9

Comment: ok, if you will change `management.endpoints.web.exposure.include=health,metrics` to `management.endpoints.web.exposure.include=*` is it work ?

Comment: After updating <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
            <version>2.7.15</version>
        </dependency> , and setting management.endpoints.web.exposure.include=*  - getting   Exposing 1 endpoint(s) beneath base path '/actuator , but still cannot access to /actuator/metrics

Comment: if you also will add `management.endpoint.metrics.enabled=true` is it work ?

Comment: Tried with management.endpoint.metrics.enabled=true - still same issue

Comment: `management.endpoints.web.exposure.include="*"` something have you tried ?

Comment: also `org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-actuator-autoconfigure` dependency, have you added ?

Comment: also can you check if `/actuator/metrics` is present in `/actuator` endpoints path list

Comment: Changed  definitions as following : management.endpoints.enabled-by-default=true
management.endpoints.web.exposure.include=*
management.endpoint.metrics.enabled=true , When accessing /actuator/health or /actuator/info - got result  
but when  accessing  /actuator  or /actuator/metrics - got 404 .   In the app log appears that :  Exposing 20 endpoint(s) beneath base path '/actuator'   but cannot see list of them

Comment: if you will access `/actuator` can you see the ref to `/metrics` ?

Comment: `management.endpoints.web.exposure.include: metrics`